# Reading XML Strings from Java

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

With something that I thought was so simple, I'm surprised to be getting such a strange error...

In my program, I have a layout with 5 buttons on it.  When you press a button, it launches the phone's dialer with the number pre-loaded into it.  I've had no problem with this before, but then I tried moving the phone numbers to strings in an XML file that I put in the /res/values folder called 'phone.xml'.  Here's a portion of my code for the Java file:

```
    public void launchDialer(String number){
        String numberToDial = "tel:"+number;
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.police_button1:
            launchDialer(Integer.toString(R.string.police1_phone));
            break;
        case R.id.police_button2:
            launchDialer("" + R.string.police2_phone);
            break;
        case R.id.police_button3:
            launchDialer("" + R.string.police3_phone);
            break;
        case R.id.police_button4:
            launchDialer("" + R.string.police4_phone);
            break;
        case R.id.police_button5:
            launchDialer("" + R.string.police5_phone);
            break;
        }
    }
```

And here's my phone.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="police1_phone">"555-555-5555"</string>
    <string name="police2_phone">1-800-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police3_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police4_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police5_phone">555-555-5555</string>
</resources>
```

As you can see in the Java file, I tried something different for police1_phone and police2_phone, but neither of them worked. You can also see I tried putting quotes around 1 of the phone numbers in the xml file, but it still didn't work.  My output has always been some random 7 digit number that wasn't even close to the phone number I wanted it to print. This Java code worked:

```
launchDialer("555-555-5555");
```

But, I **need** it to read from an XML file.  Any ideas?

Comment: "neither of them worked" doesn't give us much information. What happened? Did you get an exception? What was the value of `R.string.police2_phone` at execution time? Basically there's a bunch of diagnostics missing here...

Comment: As I mentioned, I gave me a random 7-digit number in the dialer.  The number it gave me was '213-096-8576', which was far from the actual number, which was '978-937-xxxx'.  No matter how I worded the Java/XML file as described above, they all gave me random 7-digit numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand something, but `getString(R.string.police1_phone)` must work.

Comment: I don't why any of my other attempts don't work, but this works. Thank you!

Comment: Because you were using the id of the resource(generated in the R class), not the value itself.

Comment: Yes, @Adinia is right. Id is just an integer which you can use to load a resource. Ids are generated by the Resource Compiler so they're just random numbers for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want they are ready to use parsers like

- SAXXParser (which i allways use)
  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2002/jw-0517-sax.html
- JAVAXML:
  http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/
- you could write your own little parser if you want.

Comment: The world does not need another Java XML parser

Comment: Yeah but it's easy writting your own if it's only for little use like this case =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `R.string.xxx`, then you need to put your string values in a file named `strings.xml` in your `/res/values/` folder.

Comment: I would, but my strings folder is full of a bunch of other strings (this project is relatively huge; this phone portion is a very small section of the project).  The reason I want it in a separate local file is because eventually I want to move on to parsing the phone numbers from an online xml file, if that makes sense.